# JS how to do a double each.for

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

for a gaming app, a player can select card types for his/her deck (first eachfor) and amount of each card type (2nd each.for). After this, I want to push this selection in an array.
Following part of my code works well:

```
//defining card types
let availableRoles = ["werwolf", "dorfbewohner", "seherin", "hexe", "jaeger", "armor", "heiler", "prinz"]
let gameState = {
  roles: {}
}
//set card amount 0
;(() => {
  availableRoles.forEach(role => gameState.roles[role] = 0)
})()
//adding & subtracting roles
const addRole = role => {
  gameState.roles[role]++
  document.getElementById(role + "_btn_remove").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById(role + '_cnt').innerHTML = gameState.roles[role];
  document.getElementById('total_cnt').innerHTML = totalNumberOfRolesInGame();
}

const removeRole = role => {
  gameState.roles[role]--
  if (gameState.roles[role] <= 0) {
    gameState.roles[role] = 0
    document.getElementById(role + "_btn_remove").disabled = true;
  }
  document.getElementById(role + '_cnt').innerHTML = gameState.roles[role];
  document.getElementById('total_cnt').innerHTML = totalNumberOfRolesInGame();
}

const totalNumberOfRolesInGame = () => Object.values(gameState.roles).reduce((a,c) => a + c)
```

Now I want to hit every role and hit every number insider the role by using for each command. But it does not work.

```
 var rollen = []   

  function Holmir() {  
  ;(() => {
      gameState.roles.forEach(element => element.forEach (myRole => rollen.push(myRole)) 
    ) })() 
{
```

I'm thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` works with an array.

```
gameState = {
  roles: {}
}
```

`gameState.roles` gives you an object so `forEach` won't work with this